# SharedPreferences not working properly

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Please see code below

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("screenPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putString("active_screen", activeScreenText);

    if(edit.commit()){

        Log.i("APP", "SAVED!!"); // LOGCAT Always execute this piece of code

    }
}


// onCreate
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("screenPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    activeScreen.setSummary(pref.getString("active_screen", "Never"));
```

When user choses an option from ListPreference, that option is saved in "activeScreenText" variable. If i restart the application (Home button, and navigate back to it) it works perferct. String is loaded and summary for this preference is set. But if android kills my app (or if i FORCE CLOSE it ), then this change is not persistent. I get "Never" everytime my app goes out of memory, but corresponding list preference stays at the same value.

(I have few options in listpreference and i would like to set summary, which value is current chosen. )

For example:

ListPreference:
-Never
-Choice1
-Choice2
-Choice3

Let's say i choose Choice3.
Summary is set correctly when i choose value. If i exit application and restart it again, it loads perferct. If my app is force closed or killed by android, then Choice3 is still selected but my summary value is default ( Never ).

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: if(edit.commit()){ , i do not understand at here

Comment: this is just check..if commit() actually saves preferences...and it does. I can ommit this piece of code with only "edit.commit()" and , it executes the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your values to `sharedpreferences` right after edit, not in the `onStop()` method

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfect. Can you explain why this happens (even onStop was called )

Answer (score 1):

`OnStop()` is **not guaranteed** to be called. Never rely on it for saving important data. As documentation says:

> Note that this method may never be called, in low memory situations
>   where the system does not have enough memory to keep your activity's
>   process running after its onPause() method is called.

Also, why are you saving preferences every time in such a way ? Save it when user interacts with it or just follow [Android's settings pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/settings.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move you `onStop()` code to `onPause()` event. Maybe this will solve you problem.